# Checking for open ports in python

Tags: python, port, python-sockets, port-scanning

I am learning hacking from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NQ2aMxBYNE&t=2102s) tutorial on youtube. Around *1:11:30* (timestamp), he tries to check for open ports on the ip of his own router and on http://testphp.vulnweb.com. He gets 4 ports as open for each. When I run my code I only get port 80 open on my router and none on http://testphp.vulnweb.com.

This is my **Code**:

```
import socket
from IPy import IP


def check_ip(address):
    try:
        IP(address)
        return address
    except ValueError:
        return socket.gethostbyname(address)


def scan(target):
    ip_address = check_ip(target)
    print(f"\n[-_0 Scanning Target] {str(target)}")
    for port in range(1, 100):
        scan_port(ip_address, port)


def scan_port(ipaddress_, port_):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.settimeout(0.5)
        sock.connect((ipaddress_, port_))
        print(f'[+] Port {str(port_)} is open')
    except:
        pass


targets = input("[+] Enter Target(s) to scan (split multiple targets with , ): ")

if ',' in targets:
    for target in targets.split(','):
        scan(target.strip(' '))

else:
    scan(targets)
```

And this is the **output**:

```
[+] Enter Target(s) to scan (split multiple targets with , ): 192.168.1.1 , testphp.vulnweb.com

[-_0 Scanning Target] 192.168.1.1
[+] Port 80 is open

[-_0 Scanning Target] testphp.vulnweb.com
```

**So, where am I going wrong?** Is it a problem with my connection? my code? or is this normal, and if it is then why is the guy on youtube getting a different result?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the other ports are still open on http://testphp.vulnweb.com ?

Comment: @SecurityObscurity Sorry I'm not sure, how can I check that?

Comment: Run a port scan on the target host. Perhaps using nmap. See if ports are open in the first place and compare outputs of the two.

Comment: @SyedHasan I ran an online port scan from https://hackertarget.com/nmap-online-port-scanner/
It showed that port 80 was open and few of them had filtered written beside them and their respective protocol

Comment: You can always open another port on the router or close port 80 and run your scan to see whether the result is what you expect.